# How to rotate the physics or dynamic body along an arc path in cocos2d(box2D)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, box2d-iphone, bezier

As I am newbie to cocoa2d I am struggling alot to rotate the physics or dynamic body along an arc path.

The way I tried is as follows:

```
#define COS_ANIMATOR(position, timeCount, speed, waveMagnitude) ((cosf(timeCount * speed) * waveMagnitude) + position)

#define SIN_ANIMATOR(position, timeCount, speed, waveMagnitude) ((sinf(timeCount * speed) * waveMagnitude) + position)

CCSpriteBatchNode *pipe_parent = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"pipe.png" capacity:100];
        CCTexture2D *pipeSpriteTexture_ = [pipe_parent texture];

        PhysicsSprite *pipeSprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithTexture:pipeSpriteTexture_ rect:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,55,122)];

        //pipe = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pipe.png" 
                                              // rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 122)];

        [self addChild:pipeSprite];
        // pipe.position = ccp(s.width/2 , 420.0);


        b2BodyDef myBodyDef;
        myBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody; //this will be a dynamic body
        myBodyDef.position.Set(((s.width/2) - 90)/PTM_RATIO, 420.0/PTM_RATIO); //set the starting position
        myBodyDef.angle = 0; //set the starting angle

        b2Body* staticBody = world->CreateBody(&myBodyDef);


        b2PolygonShape boxShape;
        boxShape.SetAsBox(1,1);

        b2FixtureDef boxFixtureDef;
        boxFixtureDef.shape = &boxShape;
        boxFixtureDef.density = 1;
        boxFixtureDef.userData = pipeSprite;
        boxFixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = -1;
        staticBody->CreateFixture(&boxFixtureDef);
        [pipeSprite setPhysicsBody:staticBody];

-(void) draw
{
    //
    // IMPORTANT:
    // This is only for debug purposes
    // It is recommend to disable it
    //
    [super draw];


    const CGPoint newSpritePosition = ccp(COS_ANIMATOR(150, mTimeCounter, 0.05,50), SIN_ANIMATOR(400, mTimeCounter, -0.05, 50));

    pipeSprite.position = newSpritePosition;

    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );

    kmGLPushMatrix();

    world->DrawDebugData(); 

    kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```

on following this approach my sprite rotating in circular motion instead of rotating in an arc path.

Please give your ideas or suggestions.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you are looking to accomplish when you talk about rotating in an arc path.  I only see you setting a position, not a rotation, so are you just wanting to set a position, or a rotation, or both?  Your position code looks like you are trying to achieve a circular (or elliptical) path because you are using the sine and cosine in the x,y position.

If you're looking to move a sprite along a sine curve, I did that today and it took a bit of trial and error.  I had some variables for the amplitude and period, and from there I traced out a nice sine curve movement in the sprite's update: method.

```
CGPoint initialPosition; // set this to the sprite's initial position
float amplitude; // in points
float period; // in points
float y, x = initialPosition.x;
-(void) update:(ccTime)dt
{
   x += dt * 100; // speed of movement across the screen.  Picked by trial and error.
   y = initalPosition.y + amplitude * sinf((x - initialPosition.x)/period);
   sprite.position = ccp(x,y);
   sprite.rotation = cosf((x - initialPosition.x)/period); // optional if you want to rotate along the path as well
}
```

Don't know if this is anything you are looking for but it might give you some ideas.